# Javascript Countdown timer using SQL variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to javascript/jquery. I found the following example on the internet and I am trying to get it working with my SQL variable. But I am stuck because all it does is count down from 60 over and over again..

What I am trying to accomplish is the following. I have a variable which says how many seconds a user needs to wait before it can perform the action again `$secs`. What I need is to have the time and process-bar countdown with the seconds from the variable to zero. After that I will add a page reload line to it. But first the timer needs to work. I would really appreciate any help as I can not find any workable solution/explanation for my problem.

```html
    <div id='timer'></div>
    <div id='progress' style='background:red; height:5px;'></div>
    <script>
    function started(duration) {
        var TotalSeconds = "<?php echo $secs; ?>";
        var documentWidth = $(document).width();
        var start = Date.now(); 
        var intervalSetted = null;
    
        function timer() {
            var diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
            var seconds = (diff % 60) | 0;
            seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
            $('#timer').html("00:" + seconds);
            var progresBarWidth = (seconds * documentWidth / TotalSeconds);
    
            $('#progress').css({
                width: progresBarWidth + 'px'
            });
    
            if (diff <= 0) {
                clearInterval(intervalSetted);
            }
        }
    
        timer();
        intervalSetted = setInterval(timer, 1000);
    }
    
    started("<?php echo $secs; ?>");
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to `convert` duration to time format.

```
<div id='timer'></div>
<div id='progress' style='background:red; height:5px;'></div>
<script>
function started(duration) {
    var TotalSeconds = duration;
    var documentWidth = $(document).width();
    var start = Date.now(); 
    var intervalSetted = null;

    function timer() {
        var diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        var seconds = (diff % duration) | 0;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        var date = new Date(0);
        date.setSeconds(seconds);
        var timeString = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);

        $('#timer').html(timeString);
        var progresBarWidth = (seconds * documentWidth / TotalSeconds);

        $('#progress').css({
            width: progresBarWidth + 'px'
        });

        if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalSetted);
        }
    }

    timer();
    intervalSetted = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

started("<?php echo $secs; ?>");
</script>
```

```js
function started(duration) {
    var TotalSeconds = duration;
    var documentWidth = $(document).width();
    var start = Date.now(); 
    var intervalSetted = null;

    function timer() {
        var diff = duration - (((Date.now() - start) / 1000) | 0);
        var seconds = (diff % duration) | 0;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
        
        var date = new Date(0);
        date.setSeconds(seconds);
        var timeString = date.toISOString().substr(11, 8);
          
        $('#timer').html(timeString);
        var progresBarWidth = (seconds * documentWidth / TotalSeconds);

        $('#progress').css({
            width: progresBarWidth + 'px'
        });

        if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalSetted);
        }
    }

    timer();
    intervalSetted = setInterval(timer, 1000);
}

started(60);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='timer'></div>
<div id='progress' style='background:red; height:5px;'></div>
```

Comment: Thank for you input. But I do not see my SQL/php $secs variable that has the secconds comming back in you answers. Also the progress bar is not degressing when the timer counts down?

Comment: I treid the example with the started and in there the echo for my secconds. It gives me the following error. Uncaught RangeError: Invalid time value
    at Date.toISOString (<anonymous>)
    at timer (index.php:126)

Comment: I tried the last example. Changed started(60); to started('<?php echo $secs; ?>'); and this seems to do the trick ! Thanks for you help !

Comment: I accepted your answer. Thanks for your help !

Comment: Maybe you know this to ( I hope so) How do I make the page reload afhter the timer reaches zero? I tried adding it right after the   if (diff <= 0) {
            clearInterval(intervalSetted); location.reload(); But this causes the page to reload all of the time when the timer is timed out.

Comment: Yes because `started()` will call every time on page load.

Comment: Thanks! changed it like thise so that is solved. if ('<?php echo $secs; ?>' > 0) {
started('<?php echo $secs; ?>');
}. Then one  more question. Obviously the width bar is resetted every time the page is reloaded. How do i set a start witdth and then the countdown witdth?

Comment: Please ask this as a separate question. StackOverflow rules are one question at a time.

Comment: Ok, will do! Thanks for the reaction!